# Angular2 - Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'InMemoryWebApiModule', function calls are not supported.

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-http

I am new to angular js and typescript. I started by following the angular2 **Tutorials of Heroes** in the documentation. But I ran into an error in the last section of Tutorials i.e. *HTTP*, link mentioned below:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module'

// Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService }  from './apis/in-memory-data.service';

import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail/hero-detail.component';
import { AppmainComponent } from './appmain/appmain.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

import {HeroService} from "./hero.service";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HeroesComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    AppmainComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)
  ],
  providers: [HeroService],
  bootstrap: [AppmainComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**in-memory-data-service.ts**

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    let heroes = [
      {id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice'},
      {id: 12, name: 'Narco'},
      {id: 13, name: 'Bombasto'},
      {id: 14, name: 'Celeritas'},
      {id: 15, name: 'Magneta'},
      {id: 16, name: 'RubberMan'},
      {id: 17, name: 'Dynama'},
      {id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ'},
      {id: 19, name: 'Magma'},
      {id: 20, name: 'Tornado'}
    ];
    return {heroes};
  }
}
```

The error that I get in terminal is as follows:

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'InMemoryWebApiModule', function calls are not supported. 
Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol AppModule in /home/jainam/Projects/WebstormProjects/angularheroes/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /home/jainam/Projects/WebstormProjects/angularheroes/src/app/app.module.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `angular-in-memory-web-api` instead of `angular2-in-memory-web-api`. It solved the issue for me.

Comment: I tried that as well, it didn't fix the issue. What version of in memory api are you using in your package.json?

Comment: @Jainam/@Chris - Did you guys find any solution?

Comment: @ThoughtfulMonkey, I had given up on that and did JSON parsing directly through HttpClient after that. Didn't check the docs for a long time. https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score -1):

```
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0"
```

Comment: How is this different compared to previous answer, please elaborate.